# Android DownloadManager doesn't work in some circumstances

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager

I'm using DownloadManager (Android, Java) to download files over WI-Fi from a machine in the same LAN. It works flawlessly on most of the phones I tested, but it appears that on some devices the download just doesn't start when WAN cable (Internet) is unplugged from the router (!). Everything gets back to normal on these phones when I'll connect the Internet cable. Other phones download the files without issues no matter if the Internet is connected to the router or not. This is puzzling me for over a week. There are no clues in logcat (download just doesn't start without any error). It's very odd as the Internet shouldn't have anything to do with the downloads. Everything is happening in the LAN. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Anecdotal, but I suspect some Android variants will refuse to try to download anything over a wifi connection if it determines the wifi connection in use has no connectivity to the internet (which it won't if you unplug your router's cable.) I suspect downloading files "locally" is a corner case rare enough that they simply didn't consider it. I'm certainly not aware of a way to turn this functionality off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it finally turned out the Fetch library also introduces the same problem. What worked for me, in this case, was crafting my own downloader with AsyncTask and InputStream.

Answer (score 0):

You can set setAllowedNetworkTypes flag.
refer this -> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setAllowedNetworkTypes(int)

Comment: Thank's for trying but no. As I supposed it's still not working. This setting by default is set to enable Wi-Fi and mobile network downloads so It couldn't block me. Probably @Michael Berry is right that downloading files in the local network is such a rare scenario that they didn't care to implement it. I'll try with alternative download solutions probably.

Comment: You can also use Fetch library for downloading purpose. It's light weight and easy to implement.

Comment: Yes, this Fetch library (https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch) looks very interesting indeed. I'll give it a shot. Thank you and +1 for this :)